# `open_http': 500 Internal Server Error (OpenURI::HTTPError)

Tags: ruby, json, http, parsing

I'm trying to parse a url but keep having this 500. Any suggestion please?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gregclermont/ca9e8abdff5dee9ba9db/raw/
7b2318efcf8a7048f720bcaff2031d5467a4a2c8/users.json'
encoded_url = URI.encode(url)

open(encoded_url) do |stream|
  quote = JSON.parse(stream.read)
  puts quote
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gregclermont/ca9e8abdff5dee9ba9db/raw/7b2318efcf8a7048f720bcaff2031d5467a4a2c8/users.json'

open(url) { |f| JSON.parse(f.read) }
```

Works fine for me.